# How do you remove all parts of a string that don't start with a certain character or characters?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've got a python string that has a bunch of text and I want to remove all parts of the string that don't start with the character: 5, what would the code for that be?

I tried to format the string but I'm just not sure how to do it.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You won't get any useful answers if you don't add some examples of what you are trying to do, as well as any code you've tried so far, and why it didn't work (be specific).

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "start" of a part of the string? A string has only one start, namely the first character. Do you define "start" as the first character after a space? Or maybe the first character after a "\n" (new-line character)?

Comment: It would be nice to at least see [a part] of the string in question, so one could think of a possible answer.

Comment: lets say the string is: " 65789 01234 56779" how would you remove the parts of the string that don't start with 5? in this instance, that would be 65789 and 01234

Answer (score 1):

If you have a string `"65789 01234 56779"` and seek a result of `"56779"` that is:

> remove the parts of the string that don't start with 5

per you comment, then I think the easiest path forward is to split the string into "parts" (presumably based on whitespace) and discard any part that does not itself start with "5".

Note that the `re` package can get much more nuanced with respect to word boundaries and punctuation.

```py
text = "65789 01234 56779"
text_parts = [
    part
    for part
    in text.split()
    if part.startswith("5")
]
print(" ".join(text_parts))
```

That should give give you `"56779"`

Answer (score 0):

Think of this:

```
s="""Fusce convallis metus id felis luctus adipiscing. Pellentesque egestas, neque sit amet convallis pulvinar, justo nulla eleifend augue, ac auctor orci leo non est. Fusce vel dui. Sed augue ipsum, egestas nec, vestibulum et, malesuada adipiscing, dui."""
delimiter=" "
excluder="a"
r=[]

print(s)
for i in s.split(delimiter):
 if i[0]!=excluder: r.append(i)
print(" ".join(r))
```

The string is split up at all space characters, checked for the initial letter and rejoined to the final string.
This omits all words in the string starting with the letter "a" (I chose "a" as no word started with "5"). The output:

```
Fusce convallis metus id felis luctus adipiscing. Pellentesque egestas, neque sit amet convallis pulvinar, justo nulla eleifend augue, ac auctor orci leo non est. Fusce vel dui. Sed augue ipsum, egestas nec, vestibulum et, malesuada adipiscing, dui.
Fusce convallis metus id felis luctus Pellentesque egestas, neque sit convallis pulvinar, justo nulla eleifend orci leo non est. Fusce vel dui. Sed ipsum, egestas nec, vestibulum et, malesuada dui.
```

I hope this is what you need. As you can see, some punctucation also got lost. So the task can get elaborated, but therefore a better problem description must be made available.

**Edit:**

```
s="65789 01234 56779"
delimiter=" "
excluder="5"
r=[]

print(s)
for i in s.split(delimiter):
 if i[0]!=excluder: r.append(i)
print(" ".join(r))
```

Result:

```
65789 01234 56779
65789 01234
```

Comment: this is almost what I needed, but it's kinda the opposite, is there a way to make it keep the 56779 and get rid of the others?

Comment: change != in the if-clause to ==